# What happens if you manifest a Zoetic Cavern?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-face-down-cards

If I manifest [Zoetic Cavern](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=442238) can I use it's morph cost as usual, the reason why I ask is because manifest says you can turn it face-up only if it is a creature card, which it is not, so I was wondering if that applied to only the manifest, face-up cost or if it keeps you from turning it face-up with other morph costs?

I'm assuming a card can have multiple morph costs that don't necessarily interact with each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the morph cost of the Cavern.

In [the rules for manifest](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Manifest) rule 701.33c says:

> If a card with morph is manifested, its controller may turn that card face up using either the procedure described in rule 702.36e to turn a face-down permanent with morph face up or the procedure described above to turn a manifested permanent face up.

So if you are turning a card face up using the morph procedure, the manifest procedure and its restrictions become irrelevant.

Manifest is a separate, though similar, mechanic from morph and it is incorrect to call the cost of turning a card face up using the manifest procedure a morph cost.